# Neo4j and immutable objects

Tags: java, neo4j, immutability

How can I store/load immutable objects with Neo4j?
I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.9 with spring-data-neo4j 4.2.9.

Say I have an immutable object that I want to store in Neo4j:

```
public class Element {

    @GraphId
    private final Long id;

    private final String name;
    private final Int atomicWeight;

    // Getters, AllArgsConstructor, NoArgsConstructor ommitted
}
```

When loading such an object Neo4j would throw this:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.MappingException: No identity field found for class: com.example.Element
```

I'm assuming Neo4j first creats an object with the default constructor and then populates the fields using setters (for mutable objects) and reflection (for immutable objects).

If the fields are not `final` everything works fine.

I know that some libraries (Jackson, for example) don't have any issues with final fields and work in the same way (create empty instance and populate later using setters/reflection). So, is there a way to make Neo4j gracefully handle immutable objects?

Comment: Did you check if `@Immutable` (see: http://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/util/Immutable.html) would suit your needs?

Comment: Tried it, `@Immutable` doesn't help